# Examples of C++ classes not binary moveable

Tags: c++

Does anyone know of **any** C++ class which are not binary moveable?

In other words, do you know **any** class where this results in memory-leak or undefined behaviour?

```
{ // New scope
// Allocate some memory
unsigned char data1[sizeof(MyClass)];
unsigned char data2[sizeof(MyClass)];
// Create an instance of the class
::new (data1) MyClass();
// Create a pointer and run some class-specific code
MyClass* ptr = (MyClass*) data1;
ptr->MyFunction();
// Binary move everything to data2
::memcpy((void*)data2, (void*)data1, sizeof(MyClass));
::memset((void*)data1, sizeof(MyClass), 0); // for clarification
// Run some code at the new memory location, same object
ptr = (MyClass*) data2;
ptr->MyFunction();
// Run destructor at memory location2
(&*data2)->~MyClass(); 
} // ... out of scope. No implicit destructors called. No memory leaks.
```

*Update*:

1. By binary moveable I mean any object which can be binary moved to another location in memory and still function properly (the move constructor could be implemented with memcpy()).
2. Of course any object which has pointers pointing to them cant be moveable, that's not part of the question.
3. (clarify) tr1::smart_ptr, std::deque, std::vector and std::list and like classes *can* be binary moveable so dont bother arguing about thier internal behaviour when reallocating nodes.
4. (clarify) Classes handling memory allocation can be binary movable, as a binary *move* means you are not handling both objects after the move, and the destructor wont be called twice.

Comment: What do you mean by "binary moveable"?

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: He most likely means that one can't use `memmove()` to change that object location in memory.

Comment: And how can a class point to itself?

Comment: You can read this proposal about default move functions : http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2583.html. They evoke the problems of pointers and references in moveable objects.

Comment: I'm nitpicking, but you shouldn't use `memcpy()` for moving objects - you should use `memove()` instead.

Comment: @Philipp: int* mPtr = &mValue;

Comment: @Viktor Sehr: That means you have an `int` object `mValue` and an `int` pointer `mPtr`, but no class and nothing pointing to itself. Do you mean something like `void* that = this`?

Comment: @Philipp: he means that one member is a pointer that points to another member (or to the class instance itself). The pointer must be updated if the object moves.

Comment: @tomekszpakowicz: Yes, and why can't I move an object (or more typically - an array of objects) with a source/destination overlap? If I delete an element from an array and need to move the tail - it's exactly that situation.

Comment: @sharptooth: You *can* move an object if source and destination overlap, using `memmove`, as __tomekszpakowicz__ said.

Comment: @sharptooth Sorry! I misunderstood your comment. You sounded like you were saying that one should use `memmove()` instead of `memcpy()` becouse it moves.

Comment: -1 a) For not just ignoring the elephant in the room but also downvoting anyone for simply mentioning that there is one, and b) for posing a question just to get specific answer: "No, there are no C++ classes that are not binary moveable" and then changing the question and the definition of _binary moveable_ until you get this answer.

Comment: How is this a move? It copies the class instance, it doesn't move.

Comment: I don't understand your updates 3 and 4. How do you propose to prevent the destructor from being called twice? And how can something like `std::vector` be binary movable?

Comment: jalf: update the code. the destructor is only called explicitly

Comment: @tomekszpakowicz: I havent changed the definition of binary moveable?

Comment: @Viktor: you have, in (3) you've said that `std::list` is binary moveable _by definition_ [sic], even though it is not per the defintion of (1)

Comment: @MSalters: What do you mean? std::list is fully compliant with (1).

Comment: @Viktor: and that's why you got the downvotes: you keep insisting, even though the standard is very clear that (1) covers only POD objects, while `std::list<T>` is definitely not a POD.

Answer (score 8):

If any other object stores a pointer to your object your object is no longer binary moveable (also called bitwise moveable). A doubly-linked list element is a good example. When you want to relocate an element of a doubly-linked list you need to adjust pointers in the adjacent elements. So if you try to only use `memmove()` to relocate the element the list breaks.

Comment: Similarly, if anything has a pointer to any member variable of your class instance, it the object is not bitwise movable.

Comment: Dont upvote this. Both a linked and a double-linked list are binary movable as thier element can stay fixed while binary moving the actual class.

Comment: @Viktor: if the list is intrusive (that is, the links are embedded in the elements rather than in a wrapper), then trivially moving the elements will break the links, just as sharptooth says.

Comment: Doesn't work either if the linked list object itself has space for one or more nodes (i.e. when it uses an optimization similar to the small-string optimization).

Comment: @Mike Seymour: But these elements can never exist on the stack.

Comment: MSalters: finally someone understands

Comment: @Viktor: what does the stack have to do with anything? You might get better responses if you ask the question you want answered, rather than complaining when people fail to read your mind.

Answer (score 3):

A class using raw memory to avoid premature construction:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
class aligned_storage
{
public:
private:
  T* mHead;
  unsigned char mData[N*sizeof(T) + std::tr1::alignment_of<T>::value - 1];
};
```

Here the issue is two fold:

- `mHead` points into the object itself, so it should be changed, of course
- even if we instead used some kind of byte count for the offset, this offset would have to be changed after the move.

And of course, any class using some subscription mechanism (observer pattern), because you would need to unsubscribe from the copied object and subscribe from the new object.

There is not much difference between using bitwise copy in a Move Constructor than for a Copy Constructor... and it's a bad idea as soon as you're dealing with non-PODs.

Answer (score 2):

Any stream class (*) will have an internal buffer, and a pointer pointing to the next character within that buffer.  They would not be binary movable.

(*) Essence of a stream class:  Provides access to some continuous stream of data, one portion (char, int, string etc) at a time.   Almost always implemented by reading a large block from the source of the data (e.g. a file) at once, and then stepping through it with a pointer.

Comment: By internal buffer, you refer to an array inside of the object? otherwise its binary-moveable

Comment: +1 Yes. Let's say the buffer size is known at compile time, so it can be put inside an object instead of allocating separately.

Answer (score 2):

- I use an offset_ptr type to build
  structures in memory blob, which I
  want to swap in and out from memory
  to disk or network, or use with
  shared memory. The offset_ptr stores
  the object location "t" as the
  distance between "this" and "t". In
  order to copy an offset pointer, the
  internal offset has to be adjusted,
  hence it can only be memmoved if the
  object it points to it memmoved by
  the same amount (which is the case
  for the aforemention memory blob).
- It is not uncommon to use an objects
  location as a key to access an
  associated resource, in particular if
  the ressource is frequently unnused
  and would add considerable overhead
  if aggregated into the object itself.
  For example, if you want every object
  to have an optional mutex, you might
  want to make up a global hash table
  where you map the objects location
  (this) to it's associated mutex,
  which is of course created only when
  actually requested. You can't memmove such an
  object anymore, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

Smart pointers, containers and other resource management classes, whose destructors are responsible for releasing resources, must be invalidated by the move. Otherwise, the old object will release the resource which should have been transferred to the new one.

UPDATE: this is an answer to the original question, which has since been changed to invalidate it.

Comment: Assuming that we are doing a true *move* (and not a copy), then those objects would be fine, as they hold pointers to external (and presumably unmoved) objects. It's only a problem if both the pointer and the thing pointed to move together.

Comment: @James: the problem is that the old object still thinks it's managing the external resource, so its destructor will release it while it should still be available; then the new object's destructor will eventually try to release it a second time (if the program hasn't already crashed). You need move semantics that invalidate the old object, and a bitwise copy won't do that.

Comment: @James: and we're not talking about a "true move"; the question is asking about implementing the move as a simple `memcpy`.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: You dont need move semantics for this, if std::vector <smart_ptr> was implemented as memcpy all elements when allocating more memory (instead of copy construct) it would still work.

Comment: @Viktor: You do need move semantics, unless you can ensure that the destructor of the old object won't be called following the move. Maybe you can do this if you're implementing a container that manages the objects (but your question makes no mention of this); in general, you'll be firmly in the realm of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: I am, as you say, talking about classes maintaining objects on thier own.

Comment: @Viktor: I've no idea what question you want answered, but I'm leaving this answer because it does answer the question you asked.

Comment: Mike: I have not changed the original question, only tried to make it more clear

Comment: @Viktor: the original question didn't mention that the objects would only be manually constructed and destructed; adding that information changes things completely. My answer assumed the more usual case of scope-based destruction, where it's generally unsafe to do a bitwise copy of anything with a non-trivial destructor.

Answer (score 1):

Some classes that hold variable-length data have allocation functions that allocate `sizeof(Class) + ExtraDataSize` in a contiguous block, and then use placement `new` to create an object in that space. In such a scheme, there is no need for the class to have a member pointer to the extra data, as it will be located at `(unsigned char*)this + sizeof(*this)`.

Obviously, such a class won't have a public copy ctor. In theory you could binary move it, but the allocator returns only a `Class*` and you won't know how much extra bytes you need to move.

Answer (score 1):

What makes C++ object hard to move is not individual objects stopping to work (within themselves) when copied. That problem touches relatively small class of objects (like objects containing pointers to themselves or objects working closely in some kind of circular reference set).

C++ objects are hard to move because:

1. **They are pointed to!** That's the number one problem. Unless you find some way to ensure that after moving all pointers to the object that might be used in the future will be updated, there is no point in thinking about moving objects at all. C++, by definition, makes it almost impossible.
2. It's hard to determine actual class (and size) of any given object at runtime. How are you going to create any general moving procedure, if you cannot determine what class the object is (without it you cannot update embedded pointers if needed), where it really starts (think: virtual inheritance) and what size it is (say what you want, but good old C structures with variable sized buffer at the end are valid C++ objects; the same goes for C arrays).

---

**Update** (after being downvoted by OP for not answering his questions)

**Exact** answers to the **exact** questions:

1. *Does anyone know of any C++ class which are not binary moveable?*

   Yes.

   **Every** single C++ class is not binary movable by definition presented in the question.
   That's simply logical.

   Instance of every C++ class can have pointers pointing to it.
   There is nothing the author of the class can do to prevent it.
   Moreover every class instance, at some point of time, certainly has a pointer pointing to it.
   So no C++ class can satisfy condition 2:
   *any object which has pointers pointing to them cant be moveable*.
   So no C++ class can be binary movable by this definition.
2. *In other words, do you know any class where this results in memory-leak or undefined behaviour? [snippet of source code follows]*

   (Ignoring the fact that question 2 is not question 1 formulated "in other words".
   Not even close. Instead I'll answer question 2 as it is by itself.)

   Yes. Many.

   There were several examples already provided.

   More examples:

   - Linked list implemented as circular doubly linked list with sentinel node embedded as a member in linked list class object itself.
     Executing this code -- assuming that first `ptr->MyFunction();` creates at least one node -- will result in undefined behavior when loop deleting nodes reaches location of old sentinel node (which is now zeroed).
   - Form (as in GUI element) containing some controls (with pointers to them as members) and listening to their events.
     If second `ptr->MyFunction();` allow events to be triggered (eg. by executing some kind of Form::Show method), it will lead to undefined behavior when event handlers try to manipulate controls via pointers which have already been zeroed.
   - If Class has sizeof == 13 (for example, exact value is not important) and its first member requires alignment on 4 byte boundary (e.g. it's a virtual function table pointer) then it is an undefined behavior because alignment of data2 does not fit requirements of Class. On some platforms it doesn't matter. On some other it will simply run much slower. On others it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's hard for you to know the exact size of your class' instances, especially taking virtual methods into account.

Comment: What's so hard about `sizeof`?

Comment: @Rob: `sizeof` only works if you know the dynamic type. If you've just got a reference to a base class, then you can't find out the size of the whole object.

Comment: Question is about _classes_ that aren't movable. While this is a case where you can't move an _object_, it's because you don't _know_ its class, not because of properties of the class itself.